# Detect if user has enabled location services on domain

Tags: javascript, browser, geolocation, gps

Is there a way to know if a user has already enabled location services for a domain in a web page script.
This is for purpose of NOT showing a button "detect location" if the user has already pressed it once in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set a cookie with a value and basically check to see if the cookie exists if it doesnt then you can "detect location"